# Select Method of Range Class Failed in VBA when Excel cell is selected

Tags: excel, vba

Very new VBA user here. I keep getting an error when I have copied over a range of cells from 1 workbook to another & then go to select a new cell. When I open the workbook that the data was copied too there is still the selection active where the data was pasted & I'm thinking this is causing the error but I would expect once I clicked a new cell the selection should cancel?

The error is occurring in the 3rd line of code:

> 'Select Method of Range Class Failed'

The strange thing is I do the same in some code earlier & it works.

```
Workbooks("PS 2019_June 19_updated (Macro).xlsm").Worksheets(8).Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Copy
Workbooks("PS & Config - Actuals & FC.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Range("a2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Workbooks("PS & Config - Actuals & FC.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Range("a1").Select
Workbooks("PS & Config - Actuals & FC.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Range("a2").Select
```

Comment: you must activate the workbook and worksheet before trying to select a cell.

Comment: Thanks Scott - the strange thing is there is code exactly the same as the above the runs before it but for different data & it works?

Comment: @Mturks83 which is probably the reason the second set does not work, the other workbook is the active workbook.

Answer (score 1):

First things first - try to avoid `.Select` and the `.Activate` from every VBA - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Concerning the error - it appears, because it is trying to select a cell in a non-selected worksheet. To avoid it, try adding this:

Before this line:

```
Workbooks("PS & Config - Actuals & FC.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Range("a1").Select
```

Write this line:

```
Workbooks("PS & Config - Actuals & FC.xlsm").Worksheets(3).Select
```

Comment: This fixed it for me.  I was cycling through all the worksheets in a For loop and it would only do the first one and stop (with the failure message in the title of this topic) before starting on the second one.  When I selected the second sheet and continued the execution, it would do the second one, etc.  I didn't realize what I was doing that made it work until I saw this post.